# how to save .init.d file using command?

Tags: 12.04, tomcat

I am trying to install tomcat7 using this link http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/install-tomcat-7-ubuntu-12-04/ . i did successfully till step 3.i got stuck in step 4 that i dont know how to save the file in terminal,

```
#!/bin/bash
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.47
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
start() {
 sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
}
stop() {
 sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
}
case $1 in
  start|stop) $1;;
  restart) stop; start;;
 *) echo "Run as $0 <start|stop|restart>"; exit 1;;
esac
```

please tell me the command to save this file,then only i can proceed for further steps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what editor you used to create the file.
If you used vi/vim then  hit the **ESCAPE** key ( that will drop you in the command mode) and type

> :wq

w -> write

q -> quit

Have a look at http://www.fprintf.net/vimCheatSheet.html for additional commands.

Comment: No problem. Have a great day!